# PyQt5: How to set SameSite/Secure headers in QNetworkCookie

Tags: python-3.x, cookies, pyqt5, qtwebengine, qtnetwork

I have some Python code which sets a cookie like this:

```
loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
profile = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile("storage", loader)
cookie_store = profile.cookieStore()

with open('cookie.txt', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()

cookie_store.setCookie(QNetworkCookie(contents))
webpage = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage(profile, loader)
```

Buit when I run the above code I get this error:

```
A cookie associated with a resource at was set with `SameSite=None` but without `Secure`
```

How can I fix that using PyQT5? How do I set `SameSite=None` and `Secure` using PyQt5?

Comment: you are setting cookies by the txt file, please also show the content

Answer (score 1):

Qt6 has a [dedicated API for dealing with SameSite](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qnetworkcookie.html#setSameSitePolicy), but there's nothing equivalent in Qt5. So, since [QWebEngineCookieStore](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginecookiestore.html) only accepts `QNetworkCookie` objects, it will be necessary to construct them from the raw cookie data instead. This can be done quite easily using Python's [http.cookie module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.cookies.html) (which will ensure everything is encoded properly):

```
from http.cookies import SimpleCookie

cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie['name'] = 'value'
cookie['name']['samesite'] = None
cookie['name']['secure'] = True
contents = cookie.output().encode('ascii')

for qt_cookie in QtNetwork.QNetworkCookie.parseCookies(contents):
    print(qt_cookie.toRawForm())
    cookie_store.setCookie(qt_cookie)
```

Output:

```
b'Set-Cookie: name=value; secure; SameSite=None'
```

See e.g. [MDN: SameSite cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite) for an explanation of the various values that can be used with SameSite. It would appear that explictly setting `SameSite=Lax` may be a better default:

```
cookie = SimpleCookie()
cookie['name'] = 'value'
cookie['name']['samesite'] = 'Lax'
contents = cookie.output().encode('ascii')
```